# Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

**TL;DR:** Пытаюсь переключиться на другую ветку, получаю это сообщение. Что делать?

---

Здравствуйте. С git знаком плохо, кроме `push/pull/clone` ничего не приходилось использовать до сегодня. Читал книгу Pro Git, но до меня так и не пришло озарение. Кто работает с git помогите с проблемой.

У меня есть 2 ветки. 1-`master`, 2-`my1` Я работал на ветке `my1`. Но тут нужно было создать новую ветку `my2` (она копия ветки `master`). Сделал `git pull` и получил на local ветку `my2` с удаленного репозитория. Но при попытке перейти на ветку git checkout my2 пишет (*Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout*). Мне нужно перейти на ветку `my2` и там уже сделать push. А ветка `my1` осталась такой как есть на удаленном репозитории. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Я в в d git тоже особо не разбираюсь, потому использую SourceTree - визуальная оболочка для управления git.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ветка `my1` уже содержит измененные вами файлы. Git просто не дает вам потерять свои изменения. Вам нужно либо комитнуть свои изменения в ветке `my1`, либо отложить их (см. команду [stash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-stash/info)).

Comment: А можно ли сделать сделать такое... находясь в ветке my1 сделать комит в my2?

Comment: @Volk Sasha Можно застешить изменения, переключиться в my2, извлечь отложенные изменения и коммитнуть.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать